# Refresh list view when button delete is clicked inside custom adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have searched this issue in this web, but nothing has helped me yet. Many people ask the same thing but none answers my problem. I have a listView with a button delete for each row of my list. I have every thing done, except get my list view updated. This list view is populated with information stored in a database. For each row, I have a custom ListAdapter and, I handle the onClick event of my delete Button inside this class.

So this is my Main Activity where I set the custom Adapter:

```
public class ClientsActivity extends ListFragment {

private Cursor mCursor;

    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_clients, container, false);

    listEmployees(view);

            ...
    }

    private void listEmployees(View view){
    //Get the list from DB and set other variables..
    ...

            ListView lvEmployees = (ListView) view.findViewById (android.R.id.list);
    ListClientCursorAdapter notes = new ListClientCursorAdapter(context, R.layout.activity_row_client, mCursor, from, to, 0);

    lvEmployees.setAdapter(notes);
     }
}
```

And this is my custom adapter class:

```
public class ListClientsCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

//Set the constructor and stuff
...
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View v = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);

    //Things that populate my rows
            ...

    ImageButton buttonDelete = (ImageButton)  v.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonDelete);

    //I set in a bundle, the id of the employee that I want to delete.
    final Bundle mArguments = new Bundle();
    mArguments.putString("id", id);

    buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());

            alert.setMessage("are you sure?"); 
            alert.setTitle("Deleting.."); 

            alert.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }});

            alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                            //I get from the bundle the Id of my employee
                    String id = mArguments.getString("id");

                    deleteEmployee(id);
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
            alertDialog.show();

        }});
    return v;
}

private void deleteEmployee(String id) {
    //Here I delete the item in the DB
            //and everything works fine ..
            ...
//SOLUTION:
            //HERE I HAVE TO REFRESH THE LIST. THIS IS HOW
            this.changeCursor(DB.listCompanies(context));
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

As I know the notifyDataSetChanged() works if I get my data for my list from an array. But this is not my case.

Any help will be apreciated!!.

**SOLUTION:** 
 Inside the method deleteEmployee I put the following code, (as you can see in the code above):

```
this.changeCursor(DB.listEmployees(context));
this.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Where

```
DB.listEmployees(context)
```

is the method that I use to retrieve the values from DB to populate the listView.

So, as you can see, I needed to change my old cursor for a new one with the data updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You requery mCursor and then call notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: you forgot to tell me to call changeCursor() method. But you were right, I needed to requery and call notifyDataSetChanged(). So your answer is accepted.

Comment: Depend I normally pass in mCursor to  my adapter so I do not need to call changeCursor(), just requery and then notifyDataSetChanged().